# Showing lots of views in a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I have a ViewFlipper that shows a lot of views. The flipper "moves" only in one direction, meaning once a view got hidden, it will never be shown again. Here's what I call to move to the next view:

```
mViewFlipper.addView(myNewView);
mViewFlipper.showNext();
```

Although this works fine I'm not sure if it's actually clean and memory friendly. Would I need to remove any of the previous views? Or can I just keep pushing new views in?

If old views had to be removed - where would I do that? With some sort of callback, that gets fired once a view becomes replaced/hidden?

EDIT: here's the complete method:

```
private void OnBtnNextPressed()
{
      mViewFlipper.addView(new TestView());
      mViewFlipper.showNext();
}
```

Comment: mViewFlipper.removeAllViews() put down this before you add view(s) and please post your code so that i can show you where should you put down this.

Comment: At the moment there isn't much more code ;-) In my activity I just call the two lines shown above whenever the user presses a "next" button. So removing all views sounds good, but wouldn't that also kill the view currently active/visible?

Comment: if views r created dynamically then n only then u can use this otherwise it is not required.

Comment: Yes, I create the views dynamically (View myNewView = new CoolView()). But I'm still not sure I understood where/when I have to free these views after they became invisible.

Comment: Generally whenever you add the views dynamically before that you have to use mViewFlipper.removeAllViews()..please post your code...so that i can help you..!

Comment: OK, I've added the complete method. As said before it is registered as an event handler for a button. I'm not sure how that would help though, as it doesn't contain any more relevant information...

Comment: mViewFlipper.addView(new TestView()) you should not add view on button click....first you have to add all the views then onClick event of button you have to call mViewFlipper.showNext()..!i think still you r confused.if you want example than i will post some code..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28866/discussion-between-pratik-and-boris)

Comment: Confused? No, I'm not. I can't create the views beforehand. 1) That won't scale. I need  a lot of views, but the device has only limited memory. So keeping only a hand full of views alive at a time seems like a good idea. 2) The views need be be created dynamically, based on information that are not available beforehand.